# using both packages ltxgrid and pdfpages together rotates body text 90 degrees

Tags: pdfpages, ltxgrid

I need to create a document with frequently changing between one and two columns and a lot of floats ((long)tables) and sometimes including a (multipage) pdf document.

When using ltxgrid and pdfpages packages together the document's body text gets rotated 90 degrees.
How can this be avoided/handled?

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,openright]{book} 

\usepackage{ltxgrid}

%include PDF
%\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
    test
\end{document}
```

Example without pdfpages
[image: without-pdfpages]

Example with pdfpages
[image: with-pdfpages]